# Merging two MySQL tables by multiple keys

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider two tables:

```
# table1
|key1|key2|key3|value1|
    1    2    3     10
    2    2    2     10
     
# table2
|key1|key2|key3|value2|
    1    2    3     20
    3    3    3     20
```

I want to be able to merge them by the existing keys so that I get:

```
|key1|key2|key3|value1|value2|
    1    2    3     10     20
    2    2    2     10   NULL
    3    3    3   NULL     20
```

If I use `table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON key1..3` I am going to loose the `3 3 3` row in the second table. If I do `table2 LEFT JOIN table` I will loose the `2 2 2` row.

Solution would be first to extract all the possible keys and then join the two tables, but this becomes too complex and I wonder if there is a simpler solution?

Comment: You want a full join which you can emulate in MySQL using a `LEFT JOIN` unioned with a `RIGHT JOIN`

Comment: @Nick Imagine that one of keyX is NULL... does the thread pointed by you will solve?

Comment: @Akina If OP says that's an issue I will gladly reopen.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wgPteChRSZBRgjSZQGQnSm/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, use

```sql
SELECT key1, key2, key3, SUM(value1) value1, SUM(value2) value2
FROM ( SELECT key1, key2, key3, value1, NULL value2
       FROM table1
     UNION ALL
       SELECT key1, key2, key3, NULL, value2
       FROM table2
     ) total
GROUP BY key1, key2, key3
```

Comment: I actually used your solution becuase the inner selects are complex and works better than the proposed fiddle.